# Running doctrine migrations from composer

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, doctrine-orm, composer-php

In my symfony project i would like to trigger the

```
php app/console doctrine:migration:migrate
```

on every

```
composer install --no-dev
```

I have read that it should be possible to place such a command in the `post-install-cmd` Section of my composer file but can not figure out how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a [Composer Script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md):

> A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined as a static method) or any command-line executable command.

Just like they do in the example:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": ["phpunit -c app/"],
    }
}
```